# complete missing time series by hour

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have time series data that I want to collapse by the hour and count.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tibbletime)

df.have <- data.frame(v1=ymd_hms("2018-01-01 01:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-01 01:24:20",
                                 "2018-01-01 02:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-01 03:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-01 03:21:20",
                                 "2018-01-01 03:22:20",
                                 #"2018-01-01 04:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-01 05:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-01 06:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-01 06:10:00",
                                 #"2018-01-01 07:00:00",
                                 #"2018-01-01 08:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-01 09:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-02 01:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-02 01:24:20",
                                 "2018-01-02 02:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-02 03:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-02 03:21:20",
                                 "2018-01-02 03:22:20",
                                 #"2018-01-02 04:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-02 05:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-02 06:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-02 06:10:00",
                                 #"2018-01-02 07:00:00",
                                 #"2018-01-02 08:00:00",
                                 "2018-01-02 09:00:00"),
                      v2=c(1, 0, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                           1, 0, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

df.have %>%
  as_tbl_time(index = v1) %>%
  collapse_by("hourly", side="start", clean=TRUE) %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  mutate(sumv2_byhour = sum(v2, na.rm=TRUE),
         countv1_byhour = n()) %>%
  distinct(v1, .keep_all = TRUE)

# A time tibble: 12 x 4
# Index: v1
# Groups: v1 [12]
   v1                     v2 sumv2_byhour countv1_byhour
   <dttm>              <dbl>        <dbl>          <int>
 1 2018-01-01 01:00:00  1.00         1.00              2
 2 2018-01-01 02:00:00  2.00         2.00              1
 3 2018-01-01 03:00:00  1.00         2.00              3
 4 2018-01-01 05:00:00  3.00         3.00              1
 5 2018-01-01 06:00:00  1.00         2.00              2
 6 2018-01-01 09:00:00  1.00         1.00              1
 7 2018-01-02 01:00:00  1.00         1.00              2
 8 2018-01-02 02:00:00  2.00         2.00              1
 9 2018-01-02 03:00:00  1.00         2.00              3
10 2018-01-02 05:00:00  1.00         1.00              1
11 2018-01-02 06:00:00  4.00         5.00              2
12 2018-01-02 09:00:00  1.00         1.00              1
```

So far so good, but I'd like to have zero counts for the missing hours. Is there another way to approach this problem that would let me use `dplyr::complete`?

Comment: I figured that `complete` is going to help me get where I need to go, but I have not found a way to let me tell complete what to expect. I think I need some other function like `seq.Date`, except for hour.

Comment: Here, I find the 'v1' is not exactly in one hour intervals.  So, I guess it is not clear about the expected

Comment: I'll update to use `collapse_by("hourly", side="start", clean=TRUE)` so the intervals are on the hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `ungroup` after the `distinct` step and then do the `complete`

```
df.have %>%
  as_tbl_time(index = v1) %>%
  collapse_by("hourly", side="start", clean=TRUE) %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  mutate(sumv2_byhour = sum(v2, na.rm=TRUE),
         countv1_byhour = n()) %>%
  distinct(v1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  complete(v1 = seq(v1[1], v1[length(v1)], by = "1 hour"), 
               fill = list(v2 = 0, sumv2_byhour = 0, countv1_byhour = 0))
# A tibble: 33 x 4
#   v1                     v2 sumv2_byhour countv1_byhour
#   <dttm>              <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1 2018-01-01 01:00:00  1.00         1.00           2.00
# 2 2018-01-01 02:00:00  1.00         1.00           1.00
# 3 2018-01-01 03:00:00  1.00         2.00           3.00
# 4 2018-01-01 04:00:00  0            0              0   
# 5 2018-01-01 05:00:00  1.00         1.00           1.00
# 6 2018-01-01 06:00:00  1.00         2.00           2.00
# 7 2018-01-01 07:00:00  0            0              0   
# 8 2018-01-01 08:00:00  0            0              0   
# 9 2018-01-01 09:00:00  1.00         1.00           1.00
#10 2018-01-01 10:00:00  0            0              0   
# ... with 23 more rows
```

Comment: very cool. i've tripped up a few times when not ungrouping. strikes again. missing `%>%` on distinct line, i think.

Comment: @EricGreen  Thanks, I forgot about the `%>%`.  Fixed it

Comment: Nice solution indeed

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that avoids using `dplyr::complete()` and instead uses the `padr` package. I find this more descriptive of what you are trying to do.

```r
df.have %>%
  as_tbl_time(index = v1) %>%
  collapse_by("hourly", side="start", clean=TRUE) %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  mutate(sumv2_byhour = sum(v2, na.rm=TRUE),
         countv1_byhour = n()) %>%
  distinct(v1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  padr::pad("hour") %>%
  padr::fill_by_value(value = 0)
#> # A tibble: 33 x 4
#>    v1                     v2 sumv2_byhour countv1_byhour
#>    <dttm>              <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
#>  1 2018-01-01 01:00:00    1.           1.             2.
#>  2 2018-01-01 02:00:00    1.           1.             1.
#>  3 2018-01-01 03:00:00    1.           2.             3.
#>  4 2018-01-01 04:00:00    0.           0.             0.
#>  5 2018-01-01 05:00:00    1.           1.             1.
#>  6 2018-01-01 06:00:00    1.           2.             2.
#>  7 2018-01-01 07:00:00    0.           0.             0.
#>  8 2018-01-01 08:00:00    0.           0.             0.
#>  9 2018-01-01 09:00:00    1.           1.             1.
#> 10 2018-01-01 10:00:00    0.           0.             0.
#> # ... with 23 more rows
```